# Customize a Plugins function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to customize a function in the Ultimate Member plugin. The function has an `add_action` like this:

```
add_action('um_post_registration', 'um_post_registration', 10, 2);
function um_post_registration( $user_id, $args ){ some code }
```

and I am trying to remove this `action` on my child theme with the following code:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded','remove_whatever', 11);
function remove_whatever() {
    if (function_exists('um_post_registration')) {
        remove_action('um_post_registration', 'um_post_registration', 10, 2);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I dont even know if its possible to override a plugins functions from a child theme but I researched online and it seems like everyone recommends to use `remove_action`. Any information would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove  if (function_exists('um_post_registration'))

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: try another actions - init, wp_loaded

Comment: Tried both and they didn't work.

Comment: 1st way - try add action and then delete in your plugin.

Comment: 2nd way - try to add action and call wp_die() in the function of action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'remove_whatever');

function remove_whatever() {    
     if(remove_action('um_post_registration', 'um_post_registration', 10)){
         //echo 'Removed';
     }else{
         //echo 'Could nt remove';
     }
}

?>
```